# No module named hyppo._utils when importing models

Tags: python, networkx

My issue is when trying to import the DCSBM model:

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import hyppo 


from hyppo.time_series import _utils as _utils 
from graspy.embed import AdjacencySpectralEmbed
from graspy.models import DCSBMEstimator 
from graspy.models import EREstimator 
from graspy.models import SBMEstimator

from graspy.models.sbm import _block_to_full, _get_block_indices
from graspy.simulations import er_np, sbm
```

**Error:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-287386449480> in <module>()
      8 from hyppo.time_series import _utils as _utils
      9 from graspy.embed import AdjacencySpectralEmbed
---> 10 from graspy.models import DCSBMEstimator
     11 from graspy.models import EREstimator
     12 from graspy.models import SBMEstimator

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/graspy/inference/latent_distribution_test.py in <module>()
     26 from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import PAIRWISE_KERNEL_FUNCTIONS
     27 from hyppo.ksample import KSample
---> 28 from hyppo._utils import gaussian
     29 
     30 _VALID_DISTANCES = list(PAIRED_DISTANCES.keys())

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hyppo._utils'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

I think hyppo._utils doesn't exist and has been replaced by hyppo.time_series and inside that folder there exists the required _utils package.

How do we fix this?

I was just trying to run the tutorial: https://docs.neurodata.io/notebooks/pedigo/graspologic/2020/09/24/latent_model_tutorial.html

Run on Google colab

This line
`from hyppo.time_series import _utils as _utils`   was added from me trying to fix the issue, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an old version of the package - it's called "graspologic" now. If you `pip install graspologic`, `from graspologic.models import DCSBMEstimator` should work fine. Just replace everything in that code that says "graspy" with "graspologic".

we're happy to answer questions on github issues as well! (I'm one of the people who contributes to the package)